# fabric js canvas how to set a ruler tool like jquery ruler

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, rulers

I'm trying to create fabric.js canvas program where the the user can select a good ruler tool to draw with on the canvas. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What you try Please Share...